# Create/Destroy queries faster than edit/update?

Tags: javascript, sql, ruby-on-rails, database, performance

Are Create/Destroy queries faster than edit/update?

If we want to add like feature to post, is better to create a new table "likes" with user_id and post_id columns or create a new column likes_number on post table?

Thank you very much.

Comment: create a field to flag a data not create a new table

Comment: of course you are the best @Hogan!

Answer (score 1):

This depends very much on many different parameters, but in general consider the following:

- Is there meta-data specific to the flag?  In the case of likes there could be:  The user that made the like, the timestamp of when the like occurred as examples.  Tracking this data in the post table would require a column for each piece of data.  If you want to store this meta data then you should use another table.
- Is there a one to many relationship?  In this case there is -- there can be many likers.   This shows that a row in another table could have value.  Every row stores the meta data for that like.
- How used is the table -- will locking have a performance impact?  In your case I doubt it but it could be the case that locking to row to change the like count could cause performance issues.  If the like data is in a different table there is no impact.

To me it seems clear that in this case another table makes sense.

Other types of data could be the other way -- for example a flag for a task being finished in a todo list.  In that case it makes sense to just add a column.

---

As for create/destory vs edit/update -- it depends so much on many details but I would say in general edit/update is faster.

Comment: For that matter, you don't need to explicitly lock a separate "like" table at all, and it doesn't much matter if you count locked rows or not on the table either.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse -- right, if there is no modifications and only inserting rows then no locking is needed.